# PoS mechanism with Ethereum client - Pantheon

Tags: ethereum, consensus, pos

I'm just putting the feelers out there to see if anyone has attempted to add a Proof of Stake mechanism to the Pantheon Ethereum client or any other Ethereum client for that matter.

With Ethereum announcing that Casper FFG hybrid will be no longer, if someone has successfully implemented Casper FFG in it's first release on a client and is willing to offer feedback/advice, that would be great.

I am fairly new this world but would like to see and test theories around different consensus mechanisms

Comment: I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reviewing the material in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon (now Besu) doesn't have POS mechanism integrated, but the PegaSys team does work on a eth2.0 client called Artemis.

https://github.com/PegaSysEng/artemis